# Is it possible to use 48V relay in 120V circuit by adding current limiting resistor and capacitor. Will this also speed up the response of the relay?

Tags: switches, relay, control, protection, coil

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB46dt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

title kinda says it all,

Was talking to another engineer and didn't quite follow how they said they could get faster trip coil response times by using a lower rated voltage coil in a much larger voltage circuit by tuning the capacitor and resistor appropriately.

The resistor would be tuned so that as the capacitor became fully charged the overall resistance of the circuit would approach a value within the rated coil current.

however when first closing the switch the coil would "slam" the relay contact shut much quicker than it normally would.

they said railway engineers used a setup like this all the time. Anyways it makes sense but I'm trying to simulate this and not seeing much improvement nor the level of current dropping to the rated current. maybe i'm missing something and was hoping someone more experienced could shed some light on what this engineer was describing.

Thanks

Edit:
added pics of my simulation, It didn't seem like changing the resistance of the inductor did much to the simulation which i found odd..

[image: Simulations]

Edit2: okay so yeah it seems to make the coil act quicker when it is a DC relay. If anyone has any ideas on how to simulate ac relay with shader rings (just learned about how shader rings work, really cool) please tell me.

[image]

Comment: What does your current graph look like?

Comment: Are you sure your engineer friend wasn't talking about **DC** relays? Railways use DC in signaling and locomotive control. In a DC circuit the initial pull-in would be aided by the capacitor charge current. This would tail off as the capacitor voltage reached the voltage of the coil / R1 potential divider voltage.

Comment: Erv, you'll need to develop a proper model for the AC relay if you want meaningful results from Spice. The AC relay you have has a shading pole ring. That helps by keeping a current in the ring when the instantaneous AC voltage approaches 0 V crossover during each half-cycle. I haven't sat myself down to work out such a model, though. But I know it would be important before you could trust much of what you see in simulation, so you could interpret whether or not the relay might latch well and what else it may mean to the relay. I honestly don't have a suggestion in mind, though. Not yet.

Comment: Depending on the size of the relay (tiny to heavy), coil inductances could range from 10µH (0.00001H) to 10H or more.  The simulation is using 10H.  If the relay is a 48VDC coil relay, it won't work from any amount of AC - it will just chatter, due to missing the shader ring as Jonk explains.  Even if it *has* a shader ring, I've seen them still refuse to work on AC.

Comment: I think you can get rid of the resistor and just use a possibly larger capacitor. The resistor would be needed for 120V DC but not AC. I don't know if the advantage of doing this will work on AC anyway since there is up to 1/240th of a second delay from 0 crossing to full Voltage. You could use a rectifier to convert to DC and then use this circuit.

Answer (score 0):

when an AC relay is idle it has lower impedance than than when it is running.

As a result if you choose the series components for the run current of the relay you may no meet the requirements for the starting current.

And if you choose for the starting current you may saturate the relay core or overheat the windings once it starts, so this seems like a bad idea in general, and to get it to work reliably you may need to do a lot of experimenting to find good component values for this.